# Is there a way to cluster networks generated from netwokx?

Tags: python, type-conversion, grouping, cluster-analysis, networkx

I'm trying to simulate an environment with minimum 300 nodes and random edges connecting the nodes. The network is generated using `networkx` in python. I want to divide this network into n clusters so that I run algorithms (like travelling salesman or tabu) in each cluster. But I can't find a good resource to do clustering / grouping.

I can successfully generate the graphs and I have previously worked on k-mean clustering, but bridging both has been difficult.
The data type generated by networkx is `multidigraph` How do I convert this to data type which I can run grouping/clustering algorithm on? (like matrix?if that's possible)
Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It's a little unclear from your question -- are you trying to detect communities within a single, 300-node graph?  Or are you trying to cluster lots of 300-node graphs as in a graph2vec approach?

Comment: I'm trying to cluster k ( k < n/10) nodes, in a graph with n (300+) nodes.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do community detection then, in which case I'd recommend using a known algorithm rather than trying to adapt k-means to the problem.  I'd suggest trying some of the algorithms [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/community.html) and seeing what fits the requirements of your problem.